# If we change the regional and language options, our ActiveX throws this error: Class Doesn't Support Automation

Tags: asp.net, .net, activex

We have an ActiveX that is working perfectly in IE running on Windows 7 ... as long as the Regional and Language Options is set to English (United States).

If we close the browser, switch to French (Canada), re-open the browser, and repeat the test, we get this error: Class Doesn't Support Automation

We've checked the registry and we don't see anything language/locale specific for our component.

Anyone know what might be causing this?

Thank you!

Glen

Comment: Are you using any DateTime variable?

Comment: Stephan - Can you be more specific?  Since we are not able to create the object, are you asking if there is a DateTime variable in the Constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the problem .. it was in the JavaScript.